# Unable to select a vertex by clicking

Tags: mesh

I can select vertices by using "b" for Box Select, but I'm unable to click a single vertex by a right-click or left-click.

When I right-click a vertex, the mouse pointer switches to another location instead.

When I left-click a vertex, nothing happens at all.

UV-Sculpt is disabled.

I wanted to select a single vertex in order to select an edge loop.

The mesh has been created by adding a cylinder, then assign "Nothing" and then using the Solidify modifier.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand where was that happening, in UV editor or in the viewport, but normally when right clicking a vertex isn't working (left clicking by default is not supposed to do anything other than placing 3D cursor), check clipping values for the camera or move view away a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactely was wrong.
I clicked "Load Factory Settings", and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

You might have switched accidently to vertex paint or some other mode. Make sure you have object/ edit mode selected. Sometimes when you mess up with an interface really bad and something doesn't work you can create a new file and than by SHIFT + F1 append your objects from saved one...